# IfxBulkCopy class doesn't exist?

Tags: asp.net, dll, .net-3.5, informix

Q:

I face the following problem.

I wanna to create an object from the following class `IfxBulkCopy` but it doesn't appear at all.

I do the following:

1- Add a reference `IBM.Data.Informix` .

2- Add `using IBM.Data.Informix;`

but in vain .

[image]

I search in the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.net_cc.doc/dqx1db2bulkcopyclass.htm) and it exists .but i can't find it .

Please help .if there is a different version or some error i made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the Common IDS .NET provider.
Basically there are two different providers that implement classes in the IBM.Data.Informix namespace.

More info [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/DB2/IDS+and+.NET+FAQs#IDSand.NETFAQs-AretherereallytwoIBM.Data.InformixProviders?)